# can we change the height of current row in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

A very simple question...

**can we change the height of only current row(the row which is clicked) in UItableView?**

Note: I dont want any affect on size of remaining rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can. You need a variable that keeps the last selected row. For ex.:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger selectedRow;
```

...
Then implement the method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == self.selectedRow) {
        return 100.;
    }

    return 44.;
}
```

and then, update the method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(self.selectedRow == indexPath.row)
        self.selectedRow = -1;
    else
        self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;

    //The magic that will call height for row and animate the change in the height
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

**NOTE**: Initialise your `self.selectedRow` with `-1` value in the beginning as the default is `0`.

Comment: You should probably make `selectedRow` an `NSIndexPath` to support a table with multiple sections.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for setting height for a row

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can place a check for `NSIndexPath` and return `height` for that particular `indexpath`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == rowtochangeheight) {
        return 60;
    }
    else
    {
        return 44;
    }


}
```

Comment: it relates to the row to which you want to change height simple

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do, But you need to save indexpath of selected row and you must intialize selectedRow variable by negative value.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedRow = indexpath.row;
    [tblView reloadData];
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == selectedRow)
        return 150.0f;

    return 30;
}
```